# Get number of positive votes from total of votes and result of all votes (+/-)

Tags: php, math

I have a query which returns the total number of votes (COUNT()) and the sum (SUM()) of all votes. A single vote is stored as a -1 or a 1.

Now I get the following and want to know what the number of positive votes is:

- SUM: -2
- Total votes: 4

What is the formula to get the number of positive (and negative) votes?

In the example the outcome is: -1 + -1 + -1 + 1 (3 negative votes and 1 positive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-x +y = sum
x + y = tot
=> 2y = sum + tot
=> y = (sum + tot)/2 ; x = tot - y
```

where `y` is the number of positive votes and `x` the negatives.

Comment: @RiaD: Yeap, I first thought he was looking only for positives:) added it explicitly anyway.

Comment: Yep. Simple and correct math. Makes you wonder if the OP thought it through before posting. Regardless, I +1'd your answer :)

Comment: Yes, this is it. Couldn't figure it out. Need a coffee i guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or in more strong mathematical terms:

[image: More strong mathematics]

[image: And then]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store negative as 0?

Positive would then be sum and negative would be total - sum.